# duplicity include-list excludes wrong files

Tags: backup, duplicity

I have a duplicity `--include-list`, which looks like this:

```
+ /data/something
+ /data/**/somethingselse
- /data
- /foo
```

which matches other files (less files) than the include-list

```
+ /data/something
+ /data/**/somethingselse
- /foo
- /data
```

The manpage says, that the first matching rule decides, if a file is included or excluded, but here the behaviour depends on the position of some unrelated rule. Why should swapping the last two lines change, what's matched under /data, especially exclude files like `/data/bla/somethingeelse`?